Dynamically copy from base image with a build arg?
I'm trying to dynamically choose which base to copy from based on a build argument, here's a stripped version my Dockerfile:
ARG PY_VER=3.12
ARG BUILD=default

# Build stage
FROM python:${PY_VER}-slim AS base_default

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade gunicorn

# Deploy stage
FROM python:${PY_VER}-slim AS build_default
ARG PY_VER
ARG BUILD

COPY --from=base_${BUILD} /usr/local/bin/gunicorn /usr/local/bin/gunicorn

COPY --from=base_${BUILD} /usr/local/lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages/

CMD ["gunicorn", "-h"]

It's fine with the PY_VER argument but BUILD unfortunately gives an error like:
Test:16
--------------------
  14 |     COPY --from=base_${BUILD} /usr/local/bin/gunicorn /usr/local/bin/gunicorn
  15 |     
  16 | >>> COPY --from=base_${BUILD} /usr/local/lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages/
  17 |     
  18 |     CMD ["gunicorn", "-h"]
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to parse stage name "base_${BUILD}": invalid reference format: repository name (library/base_${BUILD}) must be lowercase

Can anything be done to get it working?

maybe this could help?

must be lowercase

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk even if it was a lowercase, he'd get an error saying invalid format

It wouldn't surprise me if this didn't work, since newer versions of the Docker builder statically examine COPY --from=... options to figure out what build stages depend on which others.  What use case do you have for building similar applications with different library trees like this?

I'm trying to stack dependencies while keeping my code dry, for example I would make a base_django which inherits from base_default and additionally installs django, afterwards in build_default both gunicorn and django would be copied over from the site-packages. This can be done by having an if condition within the RUN of the base but separating the layers would be more flexible

So just proxy it.
ARG PY_VER=3.12
ARG BUILD=default
# Build stage
FROM python:${PY_VER}-slim AS base_default
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade gunicorn

FROM base_${BUILD} as the_chosen_base

FROM python:${PY_VER}-slim AS build_default
ARG PY_VER
ARG BUILD
COPY --from=the_chosen_base /usr/local/bin/gunicorn /usr/local/bin/gunicorn

COPY --from=the_chosen_base /usr/local/lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages/


It's a bit unintuitive but it works! thanks to @eternal-white as well
